# Log4j2 expects FilteredObjectInputStream but JPA only provides ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, hibernate, log4j2, jpa-2.1

I'm trying to save log messages generated by LOG4J2 to a DB using Hibernate and JPA, but it seems like JPA is only providing a `ObjectInputStream` but no `FilteredObjectStream`.

During my research I have noticed that this particular log4j component has been changed to be compatible with JAVA9. A short test with a compilation to Java9 hasn't worked, with the same error, either.

Is it possible to enforce the class of the inputstream in JPA?
Thank you in advance!

Components:

- Log4J2 2.11 (core & jpa)
- hibernate 5.2.16
- JPA 2.1
- JDK 1.8_151

Error message:

```
2018-04-06 13:03:25,853 XNIO-1 I/O-4 ERROR Unable to write to database [jpaManager{ description=rootLoggingDB, bufferSize=0, persistenceUnitName=loggingPersistenceUnit, entityClass=com.foo.bar.models.LogEntry}] for appender [rootLoggingDB]. org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Failed to insert record for log event in JPA manager: readObject requires a FilteredObjectInputStream or an ObjectInputStream that accepts an ObjectInputFilter
    at com.foo.bar.logging.JpaDatabaseManagerCustomProperties.writeInternal(JpaDatabaseManagerCustomProperties.java:115)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseManager.write(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:210)
    ...
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:417)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:403)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:146)
    at org.jboss.logging.Log4j2Logger.doLogf(Log4j2Logger.java:66)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.logf(Logger.java:2398)
    at org.jboss.logging.DelegatingBasicLogger.tracef(DelegatingBasicLogger.java:124)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: readObject requires a FilteredObjectInputStream or an ObjectInputStream that accepts an ObjectInputFilter
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.SortedArrayStringMap.readObject(SortedArrayStringMap.java:596)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2173)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2064)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1568)
    ...
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:782)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:767)
    at com.foo.bar.JpaDatabaseManagerCustomProperties.writeInternal(JpaDatabaseManagerCustomProperties.java:107)
    ... 16 more
```